URL path versioning with auto controllers in ABP
I'm new to ABP framework and I'm trying to apply URL versioning with auto controller, I’ve followed the documentation, but the provided code seems to add versioning as a query parameter for each API endpoint.
Is it possible to use URL path versioning with auto controllers in the ABP framework? If so, could you please guide me on how to achieve this? I've been able to implement URL versioning with explicit controllers but haven't had success with auto controllers.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Full disclosure, I'm not very familiar with ABP. Looking at the documentation, it appears to use an approach similar to how OData sets up its routing. Unless I'm mistaken, the following should configure URL-based versioning:
Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConventionalControllers
        .Create(typeof(BookStoreApplicationModule).Assembly, opts =>
            {
                opts.RootPath = "v{version:apiVersion}";
            });
});

According to the documentation, this should produce /api/v{version:apiVersion}/book/{id}. At that point, API Versioning will take over and things should just work, but I haven't tried it myself.
It's also worth noting that AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true as shown in the documentation will not not have any effect when versioning by URL segment. It's not possible to have a route parameter with a default value in the middle of a template. The only way to address that limitation is double route registration (e.g. /api/v{version:apiVersion}/book/{id} and /api//book/{id}). I'm not sure that ABP supports that. Alternatively, you can use another versioning method. It seems ABP suggests versioning by query string parameter.
